# Show that $f$ has zero inside the disk of radius $r$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f: D_{R}(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic function.

**A.** Assume that there is $r\in (0,R)$ s.t for every $z,w \in \partial D_{r}(0) \quad|f(z)|=|f(w)|$. show that in case that $f$ is not constant, it has a zero in $D_{r}(0)$

**B.** Now assume that for every $z,w \in \partial D_{r}(0)$ when $ \quad|z| = |w|$ we get $\quad|f(z)|=|f(w)|$ show that if $f$ is not constant, it has zero at $z=0$

**My ideas**

**A.** My idea here was to use the fact that according to modulus maximus  theorem $f$ has its maximum on the boundary. in addition I know that it also get it's minimum on the boundrary in (case it is not zero). $z,w \in \partial D_{r}(0) \quad|f(z)|=|f(w)|$ so I can infer that $f$ is constant, but this is  a contradiction to the given, so I can infer that $f$ does not get minimum on the boundary and than I infer that $f$ has zero in $D_{r}(0)$

B. here I think I can use the result of $A$ since I cant take $r=\epsilon$ as small as I want and hence the zero must be at $z=0$. but I do not understand how do I write it formally as a proof.

Is this approach is correct? if yes how do I formalize it? if not, what is the correct approach?

Comment: Does $\partial D_r(0)$ mean the boundary of the disk? I've not seen the $\partial$ notation used like this before

Comment: @FShrike yes this how we use it in this course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.** No, is not correct, but you are close. You cannot infer that $f$ is constant. The thing that you can infer is that its modulus is constant: Assume that $f$ is non constant. By the maximum and minimum principle and the hypothesis that $f$ is constant in the boundary, you have that $|f(z)|=M$. Notice that here I am assuming that $f$ has no zeros! (because minimum principle is applying maximum principle to $\frac{1}{f}$). Therefore, $f(D_{r}(0))=\partial D_{M}(0)$. On the other hand, since $f$ is non constant, then you can apply the Open Mapping Theorem to obtain that $f(D_{r}(0))=\partial D_{M}(0)$ is open, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $f$ has a zero on $D_{r}(0)$.

**B.** Here your idea seems correct. Since for every radius you have a zero, you have two options: you can construct a sequence of zeros which tends to $0$ (which implies that $f \equiv 0$ by the Identity Theorem), or you have a zero on $0$.

Comment: For part A, it is also a consequence of the Maximum Principle that $f$ must be constant if $|f|$ is constant and equal to the maximum on the boundary, since is reaching it's maximum